# Implementing C's enum and union in python

Tags: python, c, struct, unions

I'm trying to figure out some C code so that I can port it into python. The code is for reading a proprietary binary data file format. It has been straightforward thus far -- it's mainly been structs and I have been using the `struct` library to ask for particular ctypes from the file. However, I just came up on this bit of code and I'm at a loss for how to implement it in python. In particular, I'm not sure how to deal with the `enum` or the `union`.

```
#define BYTE char 
#define UBYTE unsigned char 
#define WORD short 
#define UWORD unsigned short

typedef enum {
    TEEG_EVENT_TAB1=1, 
    TEEG_EVENT_TAB2=2
} TEEG_TYPE;

typedef struct
{
        TEEG_TYPE Teeg;
        long Size;
    union

        {
            void *Ptr;  // Memory pointer
            long Offset
        };
} TEEG;
```

Secondly, in the below struct definition, I'm not sure what the colons after the variable names mean, (e.g., `KeyPad:4`). Does it mean I'm supposed to read 4 bytes?

```
typedef struct
{
    UWORD StimType;
    UBYTE KeyBoard;
    UBYTE KeyPad:4;
    UBYTE Accept:4;
    long Offset;
} EVENT1;
```

In case it's useful, an abstract example of the way I've been accessing the file in python is as follows:

```
from struct import unpack, calcsize

def get(ctype, size=1):
    """Reads and unpacks binary data into the desired ctype."""
    if size == 1:
        size = ''
    else:
        size = str(size)

    chunk = file.read(calcsize(size + ctype))
    return unpack(size + ctype, chunk)[0]

file = open("file.bin", "rb")
file.seek(1234)

var1 = get('i')
var2 = get('4l')
var3 = get('10s')
```

Comment: Since I don't really know python, I can't help you there, but the colons after the variable name indicate howmany Bits are used to store it (so keyPad and Accept share a byte, KeyPad residing in its first four bits, Accept in the last four)

Comment: Unions aren't necessary in Python since it doesn't use strict type checking. In your case above, you can bind both the address to an object, and a long to the same name.

Comment: @Micael Mior. Python __does__ do strict type checking - at run time. While you can bind an two different values to the same name, you can never have them __share the same address__ which is what union in C does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enums: There are no enums in the language. Various idioms have been proposed, but none is really widespread. The most straightforward (and in this case sufficient) solution is

```
TEEG_EVENT_TAB1 = 1
TEEG_EVENT_TAB2 = 2
```

Unions: [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html) has [unions](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions).

The `fieldname : n` syntax is called a bitfield and, yeah, does mean "this is n bits big". Again, ctypes has [them](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ctypes.html#bit-fields-in-structures-and-unions).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to all of your question, but for enums that you do not need a lookup-by-value on, (is, just using it to avoid magic numbers), I like to use a small class. A regular dict is another option that works fine. If you need lookup-by-value, you may want another structure though.

```
class TeegType(object):
    TEEG_EVENT_TAB1 = 1
    TEEG_EVENT_TAB2 = 2

print TeegType.TEEG_EVENT_TAB1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really need to know is:

1. [What is the size of an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c). You will use this answer to generate your unpacking code.
2. [What is the size of a union?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740577/sizeof-a-union-in-c-c). Summary: the size of the largest member.
3. How do you deal with that pointer? You should take a look at the `ctypes` module. For what you are doing, it may be easier to work with than the `struct` module. In particular, it can work with pointers arriving via C.
4. How do you coerce/cast the data read from the struct into the right type to work with in python? This is why I recommended `ctypes` in the bullet above; this module has functions for performing the necessary casts.

Answer (score 0):

The C `enum` declaration is a syntactic wrapper around some integer type.  See [Is the sizeof(enum) == sizeof(int), always?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113855/is-the-sizeofenum-sizeofint-always).  How big an `int` is will depend on the particular C compiler.  I would probably start by trying 16 bits.

The `union` reserves a block of memory the size of the largest of the contained data types. Again, the exact size will depend on the C implementation, but I would expect 32 bits for a 32-bit architecture, or 64-bits if this is compiled as native 64-bit code.  Generally speaking, you will be able to store the contents of the union in a Python integer or long, regardless of whether what has been saved in it is a pointer or an offset.

A more interesting question is why a pointer would ever be written to a disk file.  You may find that the `union` field is only treated as a pointer when the `TEEG` `struct` is in memory, but when written to disk, it is always an integer offset.

As for the :4 notation, as several people have noted, these are "bit fields," meaning a sequence of bits, several of which can be packed into a single space.  If I recall correctly, bitfields in C are packed into `int`s, so both of these 4-bit fields will be packed into a single integer.  They can be unpacked with appropriate use of Python's "&" (bitwise and) and ">>" (right shift) operators.  Again, exactly how the fields have been packed into the integer, and the size of the integer field itself, will depend on the particular C implementation.

Maybe the following code snippet will help you:

```
SIZEOF_TEEG_TYPE = 2      # First guess for enum is two bytes
FMT_TEEG_TYPE = "h"       # Could be "b", "B", "h", "H", "l", "L", "q" or "Q"

SIZEOF_LONG = 4           # Use 8 in 64-bit Unix architectures
FMT_LONG = "l"            # Use "q" in 64-bit Unix architectures
                          # Life gets more interesting if you are reading 64-bit
                          # using 32-bit Python

SIZEOF_PTR_LONG_UNION = 4 # Use 8 in any 64-bit architecture
FMT_PTR_LONG_UNION = "l"  # Use "q" in any 64-bit architecture
                          # Life gets more interesting if you are reading 64-bit
                          # using 32-bit Python

SIZEOF_TEEG_STRUCT = SIZEOF_TEEG_TYPE + SIZEOF_LONG + SIZEOF_PTR_LONG_UNION
FMT_TEEG_STRUCT = FMT_TEEG_TYPE + FMT_LONG + FMT_PTR_LONG_UNION


# Constants for TEEG_EVENTs
TEEG_EVENT_TAB1 = 1
TEEG_EVENT_TAB2 = 2

.
.
.

# Read a TEEG structure
teeg_raw = file_handle.read( SIZEOF_TEEG_STRUCT )
teeg_type, teeg_size, teeg_offset = struct.unpack( FMT_TEEG_STRUCT, teeg_raw )

.
.
.

# Use TEEG_TYPE information
if teeg_type == TEEG_EVENT_TAB1:
    Do something useful

elif teeg_type == TEEG_EVENT_TAB2:
    Do something else useful

else:
    raise ValueError( "Encountered illegal TEEG_EVENT type %d" % teeg_type )
```