# Size of Unions in C

Tags: c

How the **union** in C language allocate memory?
For example

```
union st
{
int i;
char ch;
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sizeof a union in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740577/sizeof-a-union-in-c-c)

Answer (score 4):

An instance of that union will take up at least as much space as its biggest member, i.e. 1 word for the int.

If you had a union with a `char` and a `short int`, you might end up with a word on the stack anyway, since it's more efficient in most systems to allocate on word boundaries.

Comment: I thought `int` is usually dword, not word.

Comment: @Andrey: I think yours is an x86-ism, where the "native machine word" started as 16 bit, so 32 bit integers were dword, and they kept their name even when the native machine word became 32 bit. But since the standard never mentions such terms, I'd avoid them completely, just saying that it's as big as an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

In a `union` all the members share the same memory space (or, to say it as it is specified in the standard, if you take the address of any of the members you'll get the same result - besides the type). Obviously the size of the `union` is the size of its biggest member.

Because of this, the standard allows only one of the `union` members to be "active" at the same time, i.e. if you write in `i`, then you can only read from `i`, until you write in some other member. Failure to do so results in undefined behavior, which often is getting garbage results from reinterpreting bits of the other types.

Comment: I'm not certain the assertion in your second paragraph is entirely correct: I thought the point of a union was to easily translate one type to another. (For instance, I'd use a `union{float decimal; struct{char high;char midhigh;char midlow;char low;}}` to split a float into its component bytes (or vice versa).

Comment: @CajunLuke: that's implementation-specific that is often exploited, but the standard says that reading from a member of an union after assigning to another is UB.

Comment: This ( http://ideone.com/o5icG1 ) use case outputs 12, 8 and 16 for the sizes respectively on my machine (although ideone seems to say 12, 8 and 12). To the best of my knowledge the size of  the union is not the is the size of its biggest member, but is *at least* that size and *may* be bigger.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as big as its largest member. It has to be at least that large, and there's no reason for it to be larger.

Comment: What about padding? Most compilers will report a sizeof() that makes an array of unions/structs word aligned.

Comment: But you can't assume that is the case, so it doesn't really count. I tend to think of padding as a little something extra the compiler can do if it wants: it doesn't have any impact on the size of any C construct I use.

Comment: Well, it will have effect if you write your data to storage.

Comment: That's true, but I would think you'd care about that when/if that happens. It'd be premature optimization to stress about alignment and sizeof if your object isn't ever going to be written to storage.